# How to remove python white spaces

Tags: python, regex, string, automation

I want to read from some file lines like this A = B = 411
Without any whitespaces/spaces.I have tried

```
import os
import re
import fileinput

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

fileName = "input.txt"

f = open(fileName,"r")
lines = f.readlines()
for i in lines:
    character = i.split()
    for n in character:

        if  n != '#':
            print n

        else:
            print "End of File"
```

input.txt

```
A = B = 411
C = ( D = 2 ) * _2
C = D = 2 * _2
F = C - D
E = D * _10
Z = 10 / 3
#
```

now the problem is if i give spaces between the letters/numbers in the input file the program works properly. But if the spaces are removed then the output is like A=B=411
Which i don't want..Can anybody please help me...how to maintain the integrity of the data read from the file...

Comment: i don't understand what you want ... could you give some sample input/output?

Comment: You don't want whitespace, but you also don't want to remove whitespace?

Comment: User wants to be able to include whitespace in the input, but still get the correct output.

Comment: white spaces is what making `i.split()` work and parse your input easily. If you remove them you have to write a more complicated parser. The one that recognizes number, operators and so on. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: i want to remove white spaces....i am reading from the file input.txt...and i want to maintain file contents integrity means i do not want to change the meaning ...for example...i want to read words from file but in this case if i write A = B then it is fine but if i write A=B it considers it as a whole word which i don't want

Comment: @user2217267: so if `a\s\s\s\s=\s\s\sb` then you want it as `a\s=\sb`? (`\s` is space)

Comment: @user2217267 I understand your question. But why? I'm telling you, if you remove spaces you have to write a code which is a lot more complicated than `split()`

Comment: @namit no instead of `a\s=\sb` he wants the program to be able to parse `a=b`.

Comment: @jurgenreza: means.. if `a=b` given then make it as `a\s=\sb`??

Comment: @namit sort of i think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default (i.e. with no additional arguments) a string object's[`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split)method will ignore whitespace and split the string up into a list of words. So using it, as well as with making a few other changes to simplify and speed your code up resulted in this:

```
fileName = "input.txt"
with open(fileName,"r") as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            if  word != '#':
                print word
            else:
                print "End of File"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the spaces you could replace `character = i.split()` with

```
character = list(i.replace(" ", ""))
```